# Расширенная регистрация пользователей в Django 2.1

Tags: django

Помогите решить вопрос с регистрацией через User и дополнительными полями. Для начала сделал только поле с фотографией, но в дальнейшем, возможно, расширю Profile.

Пользователь в таблице Users создается, в таблицу Profile тоже добавляется запись и поле user связывается с пользователем. Только фотографии через форму не добавляются. Через админку их можно добавить, но через форму не получается.

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Если есть какие-либо недочеты по коду (или как можно было бы сделать лучше) - сообщите о них, буду очень благодарен.

Файл **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user.username)
```

Файл **forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
from django import forms

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('photo',)
```

Файл **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, ProfileForm
from .models import Profile

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])

            new_user.save()
            new_user.refresh_from_db()

            new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            new_profile.save()

            return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {
                'new_user': new_user,
                'new_profile': new_profile
            })
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        new_profile = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'new_profile': new_profile
    })
```

Файл **register.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Create an account{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Create an account</h1>
    <p>Please, sign up using the following form:</p>
    <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {{ new_profile.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create my account"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Что значит не получается? Поле в форме игнорируется? Или ошибку пишет? Или поля на странице вообще нет?

Comment: Ошибок нет, поле отображается в форме и в request тоже видно название файла. Создается пользователь и его Profile, вот только фотография не сохраняется в Profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем, кто помогал. Сам разобрался, как можно было сделать.
Игорь правильно указал, что profile_form никак не сохранял.

Переделал следующим образом:

Вместо кода

```
new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
new_profile.save()
```

Нужно было прописать

```
new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user, photo=request.FILES['photo'])
new_profile.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Во views.py вы сохраняете только user_form, а профиль пользователя создаете через

```
Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
```

а поле photo приходит profile_form которая нигде не сохраняется. Вам нужно сделать что то вроде:

```
user_profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
user_profile.user = new_user
user_profile.save()
```

Comment: Сейчас пробую сделать
`new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user, photo=profile_form.cleaned_data['photo'])`

`new_profile.save()`
но только photo оказывается null. Может cleaned_photo нужно прописать в forms.py класса ProfileForm?

Comment: Попробовал сделать, как Вы описали, но все равное фото не сохраняется